# How can I fix the scoring on my blackjack game?

Tags: python, blackjack

I'm currently having an issue where I play a round of blackjack on the code I created, but keep losing. My score will be <21 but still more than the dealer and I will lose. I am pretty new to coding so any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
def FinalScore():
    global bank, bet

    # different win conditions
    # pays the player their original bet * 2

    if player_score == dealer_score and player_score <= 21:
        print("It's a tie!")
        bank = bank + bet
        print("You currently have $",bank,"left.")
        Restart()
    elif player_score > 21:
        print("You lost!")
        print("You currently have $",bank,"left.")
        Restart()
    elif player_score < 21 and dealer_score > player_score:
        print("You lost!")
        print("You currently have $",bank,"left.")
        Restart()
    elif player_score > dealer_score and player_score <= 21:
        print("You win!")
        bank = bet + bet + bank
        print("You currently have $",bank,"left.")
        Restart()
    elif dealer_score > 21 and player_score <= 21:
        print("You win!")
        bank = bet + bet + bank
        print("You currently have $",bank,"left.")
        Restart()
```

I tried rearranging the order of the win conditions and it did change some outcomes, but ultimately it was still finnicky. I think there is a better way to do this that I am not aware of.

Comment: @KDecker Why Code Review? The code isn't working since they are asking about how to fix a bug in the scoring logic.

Comment: Note: the line ```elif player_score < 21 and dealer_score > player_score:``` doesn't account for the dealer's score being over 21.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of conditions; In BJ, you lose if you burn (>21); but after that you win if dealer burn; after your score in compared with dealer;

```
def FinalScore():
    global bank, bet

    # different win conditions
    # pays the player their original bet * 2

    if player_score > 21:
        print("You lost!")
    else:
        if dealer_score > 21:
            print("You win!")
            bank = bank + 2*bet
        elif player_score == dealer_score:
            print("It's a tie !")
            bank = bank + bet
        elif player_score < dealer_score:
            print("You lost!")
        else:
            print("You win!")
            bank = bank + 2*bet
    print("You currently have $",bank,"left.")
    Restart()
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you use if conditions as 'case', that is what is happening with elif condition here is that it will fall on the first true statement, here `elif player_score < 21 and dealer_score > player_score:` , at this stage there is no check of the value of the dealer_score who could be greater than 21. To be more readable, try to define first what happen when a player is higher than 21, something like that :

```
if dealer_score > 21:
    print('win')
    return Restart()

if player_score > 21 :
    print('loose')
    return Restart()

else :
    if player_score > dealer_score :
        print('win')
    elif player_score == dealer_score:
        print('tie')
    else:
        print('loose')
    return Restart()
```